# How to reset the contents of a dialog in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, onsen-ui

I am building a Phonegap / OnsenUI app and have this function:

```
function showFilters()
{   
    if (typeof filterDialog === "undefined" || filterDialog==null || filterDialog=="" ) {       
        ons.createDialog('filter.html').then(function(dialog) {
            dialog.show();
            translatePage();
        }); 
    } else {
        filterDialog.show();
    }   
}
```

This all works fine, except after closing the dialog I need to reset the `filterDialog` back to `filterDialog==""` or `NULL`. How do I do that with jQuery?

Comment: Since you didn't provide any library information beside jQuery and onsenui, I assume you are using these. There is a [event](https://onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-dialog.html#event-posthide) that gets triggered. You can attach a listener to it and do your thing when it fires.

Comment: @DrColossos I will investigate that, thank you! :)